# data migration after design update

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a simple entity data model where I have two entities and a 1-* relation between them. For simplification purposes let's say Person and Book. (i.e. people have 0 or more books and books must have an owner)

The system works fine and it has data in it.

Now I need to create other entities inherited from Person (i.e. Student, Teacher)

When I create them and update my software accordingly, everything works fine with this new model.

Now I need to migrate the old data (data in Person which is linked to books)
In my data I know which person's are student and which are Teacher and I have additional information on the Students and Teachers that I'll place in the new model.

The question is how do I migrate the data. I cannot add Students and Teachers before I delete the Person instance because that would create duplicate Id in Person. I cannot delete the Person as it creates an error. ("DELETE statement conflicted with REFERENCE constraint")

How do I acheive this data migration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have mapped inheritance you should not delete `Person` - the `Person` is either `Student` or `Teacher` so you should just add correct columns (in case of TPH) or related tables (in case of TPT) and use existing data without their modification.

This migration must be done in SQL.

Comment: I'm using table per type. I was trying to do this in .NET. That's why I tried to delete the entity and then create it as a subtype. The info about which person is student and which is a teacher does not exist in the DB. That's why I was tryinh to do it in .NET.

Comment: You will not be able to do it in .NET with your new EF model because you really cannot change `Person` to sub type. It requires deletion of the person and all its relations and creating a new entity with same relations. That is a lot of not needed database operations. If it is one time migration simply create some helper tool (console application) which will take your data and execute SQL to put your database to new expected state.

Comment: This is one time thing. I ended up doing it using ExecuteNonQuery commands from the c#. Basically I've added rows to Student and Teacher tables with necessary data.